# WireMock not intercepting http request with Spring boot Integration Test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, wiremock

I have Sprint Boot Integration test with Wiremock but for some reason the Wiremock is not serving the stub response and the http request is going out to actual external api. Am I missing something? I can see from logs that the Wiremock server is starting on port 8888

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.27.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = GatewayApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RegTypeIntegratedTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(options().port(8888));


    @Test
    public void testRegType()
            throws JSONException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        wireMockRule.stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("{path}/.*/")).willReturn(
                aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withBody(new String(Files.readAllBytes(
                        Paths.get("path/regtypeResponse_stub.json"))))));


        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                createURLWithPort("/{service-url-path}y/regTypes?regtype=I"), HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                String.class);

        String expected = new String(Files
                .readAllBytes(Paths.get("path/regtypeResponse_expected.json")));

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, response.getBody(), true);
    }

    private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
        return "http://localhost:" + port + uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that was the case of some oversights in using HTTP methods but now I'm as confused as cobz. Could you explain why you need both the WireMock and your Spring Boot servers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up information of the two different servers running in your SpringBootTest. On the one handside you are telling your unit test to make your actual Spring Boot application run for the test on a random web port to simulate real calls to your webapp. This port the spring app gets assigned you are pulling into your `port` variable.

At the same time you are setting up Wiremock on port `8888` which you can also observe in your logs as stated.

Within your test you are now calling the real port of your launched spring boot app for your test through `return "http://localhost:" + port...` which is referenced in your call to the RestTemplate instance.

I think you need to separate when you really want to do a call to your running spring app, and when to your external endpoint mock by using wiremock.

Comment: I was actually missing the basic concept here where I was not configuring my backend api to go to Wiremock instance hence it was going to real/live api. I was under impression that Wiremock intercepts when it is running inside JUnit. I configured the endpoint to be Wiremock endpoint and all good

Answer (score 0):

You stubbed for `POST` method for your WireMock server but then you're invoking a `GET` method in the `TestRestTemplate` client.

You're also not expanding your path variable `{service-url-path}`.

Comment: The API that I am testing here is GET but the Backend API (stubbed) being called from this API under test is POST.